# Customise ArcMap Grid Labels Layout View

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, grids-graticules

[image]I am showing topographic profile of the route. In the Arcmap 10.7 layout view, route profile is running from right to left. So the chainage zero starts from right and increases towards left.
To show the chainage I'm using grid labels, but as my route going from right to left, grid lables are showing negative values such as 0, -100, -200 etc. as shown in the figure

I would like to see this as 0, 100 , 200, etc. without having to rotate the dataframe. Could you please help me resolving this.